# making an html5 video/audio playlist player with custom controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video, html5-audio, playlist

I'm making a HTML5 video/audio playlist player with custom controls.

I have the custom controls working for a single video but i'm having trouble binding these controls and currentTime/duration properties onto each video a user might click.

Here's [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trpeters1/EyZdy/74/) that shows what I mean.

The  code is also at the bottom of this question. Please don't be scared, the bottom 90% of the JS is the custom controls. The top 10% is defining the video object and the `on` click function to select the desired video.

I've set the default to play "video 2" of 3. The custom controls do control "Video 2".
The buttons toggle the playing/pausing of each video but you'll notice that the custom controls still control "video 2" regardless of which button was clicked.

Basically, I just need to find a way that when you click each video button that all the controls and properties (currentTime,duration) then become bound to the selected video.

HTML:

```
<button class="icon" data-id="1" >Video 1</button>
<button class="icon" data-id="2">Video 2</button>
<button class="icon" data-id="3">Video 3</button>
<div id="url"  data-id="2"></div>

<div class="videoContainer">  
<video data-id="1" width="100%" height="80%"    poster="http://www.birds.com/wp-content/uploads/home/bird.jpg" >    
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

<video data-id="2"  width="100%" height="80%"  poster="http://www.logobird.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/new-google-chrome-logo.jpg">
<source src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

<video data-id="3" width="100%" height="80%"  poster="http://cheerioscoupons.info/wp-content/uploads/_Cheerios-Coupons-1-300x283.jpg">
<source src="http://media.jilion.com/videos/demo/midnight_sun_sv1_360p.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

    <div class="progress">
        <span class="bufferBar"></span>
        <span class="timeBar"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="control">    
        <div class="btnPlay btn btn-primary" title="Play/Pause video">PLAY</div>        
        <div class="time">
            <span class="current"></span> / 
            <span class="duration"></span> 
        </div>    
        <div class="sound sound2 btn btn-primary" title="Mute/Unmute sound"></div>
        <div class="volume" title="Set volume">VOLUME
            <span class="volumeBar"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="btnFS btn btn-primary" title="Switch to full screen">FULLSCREEN</div>
    </div><!--/control-->   
</div><!--/videocontainer-->​
```

JS:

```
var url=$('#url').data('id');
var $video=$('video[data-id="'+url+'"]');
$('video').not($('video[data-id="'+url+'"]')).hide();


$('.icon').click(function(){
var id=$(this).data('id'),
    $video=$("video[data-id='" + id +"']");
$('video').each(function () {
    this.pause();
    //this.currentTime = 0;
});
   $('video').not($video).hide();
   $video.show();    
   $video.get(0).play();   
});    


//before everything get started
$video.on('loadedmetadata', function() {

        //set video properties
        $('.current').text(timeFormat(0));
        $('.duration').text(timeFormat($video.get(0).duration));
        updateVolume(0, 0.7);

        //start to get video buffering data 
        setTimeout(startBuffer, 150);

        //bind video events
        $('.videoContainer').on('click', function() {
            $('.btnPlay').find('i').addClass('icon-pause');
            $(this).unbind('click');
            $video.get(0).play();
        });

    });

    //display video buffering bar
    var startBuffer = function() {
        var currentBuffer = $video.get(0).buffered.end(0);
        var maxduration = $video.get(0).duration;
        var perc = 100 * currentBuffer / maxduration;
        $('.bufferBar').css('width',perc+'%');

        if(currentBuffer < maxduration) {
            setTimeout(startBuffer, 500);
        }
    };    

    //display current video play time
    $video.on('timeupdate', function() {
        var currentPos = $video.get(0).currentTime;
        var maxduration = $video.get(0).duration;
        var perc = 100 * currentPos / maxduration;
        $('.timeBar').css('width',perc+'%');    
        $('.current').text(timeFormat(currentPos));    

    });

    //CONTROLS EVENTS
    //video screen and play button clicked
    $video.on('click', function() { playpause(); } );
    $('.btnPlay').on('click', function() { playpause(); } );
    var playpause = function() {
        if($video.get(0).paused || $video.get(0).ended) {
            $('.btnPlay').find('i').addClass('icon-pause');
            $video.get(0).play();
        }
        else {
            $('.btnPlay').find('i').removeClass('icon-pause');
            $video.get(0).pause();
        }
    };

    //fullscreen button clicked
    $('.btnFS').on('click', function() {
        if($.isFunction($video.get(0).webkitEnterFullscreen)) {
            $video.get(0).webkitEnterFullscreen();
        }    
        else if ($.isFunction($video.get(0).mozRequestFullScreen)) {
            $video.get(0).mozRequestFullScreen();
        }
        else {
            alert('Your browsers doesn\'t support fullscreen');
        }
    });

    //sound button clicked
    $('.sound').click(function() {
        $video.get(0).muted = !$video.get(0).muted;
        $(this).toggleClass('muted');
        if($video.get(0).muted) {
            $('.volumeBar').css('width',0);
        }
        else{
            $('.volumeBar').css('width', $video.get(0).volume*100+'%');
        }
    });

    //VIDEO EVENTS
    //video canplay event
    $video.on('canplay', function() {
        $('.loading').fadeOut(100);
    });

    //video canplaythrough event
    //solve Chrome cache issue
    var completeloaded = false;
    $video.on('canplaythrough', function() {
        completeloaded = true;
    });

    //video ended event
    $video.on('ended', function() {
        $('.btnPlay').removeClass('paused');
        $video.get(0).pause();
    });

    $video.on('ended', function() {

       var nextVideo= $(this).next();
        if(!$('video').last()){
          $(this).hide();
          nextVideo.show(); 
          nextVideo.get(0).play();  
        }        
    }); //onended


    //video seeking event
    $video.on('seeking', function() {
        //if video fully loaded, ignore loading screen
        if(!completeloaded) { 
        //    $('.loading').fadeIn(200);
        }    
    });

    //video seeked event
    $video.on('seeked', function() { });

    //video waiting for more data event
    $video.on('waiting', function() {
        $('.loading').fadeIn(200);
    });

    //VIDEO PROGRESS BAR
    //when video timebar clicked
    var timeDrag = false;    /* check for drag event */
    $('.progress').on('mousedown', function(e) {
        timeDrag = true;
        updatebar(e.pageX);
    });
    $(document).on('mouseup', function(e) {
        if(timeDrag) {
            timeDrag = false;
            updatebar(e.pageX);
        }
    });
    $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
        if(timeDrag) {
            updatebar(e.pageX);
        }
    });
    var updatebar = function(x) {
        var progress = $('.progress');

        //calculate drag position
        //and update video currenttime
        //as well as progress bar
        var maxduration = $video.get(0).duration;
        var position = x - progress.offset().left;
        var percentage = 100 * position / progress.width();
        if(percentage > 100) {
            percentage = 100;
        }
        if(percentage < 0) {
            percentage = 0;
        }
        $('.timeBar').css('width',percentage+'%');    
        $video.get(0).currentTime = maxduration * percentage / 100;
    };

    //VOLUME BAR
    //volume bar event
    var volumeDrag = false;
    $('.volume').on('mousedown', function(e) {
        volumeDrag = true;
        $video.get(0).muted = false;
        $('.sound').removeClass('muted');
        updateVolume(e.pageX);
    });
    $(document).on('mouseup', function(e) {
        if(volumeDrag) {
            volumeDrag = false;
            updateVolume(e.pageX);
        }
    });
    $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
        if(volumeDrag) {
            updateVolume(e.pageX);
        }
    });
    var updateVolume = function(x, vol) {
        var volume = $('.volume');
        var percentage;
        //if only volume have specificed
        //then direct update volume
        if(vol) {
            percentage = vol * 100;
        }
        else {
            var position = x - volume.offset().left;
            percentage = 100 * position / volume.width();
        }

        if(percentage > 100) {
            percentage = 100;
        }
        if(percentage < 0) {
            percentage = 0;
        }

        //update volume bar and video volume
        $('.volumeBar').css('width',percentage+'%');    
        $video.get(0).volume = percentage / 100;

        //change sound icon based on volume
        if($video.get(0).volume == 0){
            $('.sound').removeClass('sound2').addClass('muted');
        }
        else if($video.get(0).volume > 0.5){
            $('.sound').removeClass('muted').addClass('sound2');
        }
        else{
            $('.sound').removeClass('muted').removeClass('sound2');
        }

    };

    //Time format converter - 00:00
    var timeFormat = function(seconds){
        var m = Math.floor(seconds/60)<10 ? Math.floor(seconds/60) : Math.floor(seconds/60);
        var s = Math.floor(seconds-(m*60))<10 ? "0"+Math.floor(seconds-(m*60)) : Math.floor(seconds-(m*60));
        return m+":"+s;
    };
```

​

CSS:

```
 /* video container */
.videoContainer{
width:97.8%;
height:250px;
overflow:hidden;
background:#ccc;
color:#ccc;
}
 /*** VIDEO CONTROLS CSS ***/
/* control holder */
.control{
background:#333;
color:#ccc;
width:100%;
z-index:5;   
}
.control >div{
display:inline-block;
}
.control div.btn { 
cursor:pointer;
}
.control div.text{
font-size:18px;
line-height:30px;
text-align:center;
width:20px;
}
.control div.selected{
font-size:18px;
color:#ccc;
}
.control div.sound{
background:url(/assets/img/video/control.png) no-repeat -88px -30px;
border:none;

}
.control div.sound2{
background:url(/assets/img/video/control.png) no-repeat -88px -60px !important;
}
.control div.muted{
background:url(/assets/img/video/control.png) no-repeat -88px 0 !important;
}
.control div.btnFS{

float:right;
}

/* PROGRESS BAR CSS */
/* Progress bar */
.progress {
width:100%;
height:24px;   
position:relative;
float:left;
cursor:pointer;
background: gray; /* fallback */
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#666,#333);
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#666,#333);
background:-o-linear-gradient(top,#666,#333);
box-shadow:0 2px 3px #333 inset;
-moz-box-shadow:0 2px 3px #333 inset;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 3px #333 inset;
border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
.progress span { 
height:100%;
position:relative;
top:0;
left:0;
display:inline-block;

height:100%;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
display:block;

border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
}

.timeBar{
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
z-index:10;

width:0;
background: #006DCC; /* fallback */
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#A0DCFF 50%,#3FB7FC 50%,#16A9FF 100%);
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#A0DCFF 50%,#3FB7FC 50%,#16A9FF 100%);
background:-o-linear-gradient(top,#A0DCFF 50%,#3FB7FC 50%,#16A9FF 100%);
box-shadow:0 0 1px #fff;
-moz-box-shadow:0 0 1px #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 1px #fff;
}
.bufferBar{
z-index:5;
width:0;
background: #777;
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#999,#666);
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#999,#666);
background:-o-linear-gradient(top,#999,#666);
box-shadow:2px 0 5px #333;
-moz-box-shadow:2px 0 5px #333;
-webkit-box-shadow:2px 0 5px #333;
}
/* time and duration */

/* VOLUME BAR CSS */
/* volume bar */
.volume{
position:relative;
cursor:pointer;
width:100px;
height:24px;


}
.volumeBar{
display:block;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
background-color:#006DCC;
z-index:10;
border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
}

/* OTHERS CSS */
/* video screen cover */
.loading, #init{

width:100%;
height:100%;

z-index:2;

}
#init{

cursor:pointer;
}​
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EyZdy/107/)

I have added this class on the icon click

```
 $("video[data-id='" + id +"']").addClass("active");
 $video = $('video.active');
```

so here try to select the video based on the class active and it works fine. when ever another video is clicked then remove the previous active class and add it to the newly selected video.